# What is the best practice for handling one controller with multiple entry points?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Users come to my app to enter Cards that they own.  Cards are organized by Issue such that

`Issue has_many Cards`

So our base case (1) is when a user is logged in and updating his collection, he visits

`/issues/{id}`

Which hits `issues#show` renders `issues\show.haml`.  On this page they enter or remove cards from their collection.  The page has all sorts of sorting and buttons etc...

I want to make user collections public (2), so that others can visit

`/{username}/issues/{id}`

This page would have far less going on and would display other information relevant to the logged in user, not the owner of the cards.  The obvious choice is to nest `:issues` under `:users` and make `IssuesController#show` handle everything.  But `IssuesController#show` is already handling the first case described above.

One implementation is to do:

```
class IssuesController
    def show
         if(params[:user_id])
              #do something
         elsif
              #do and render something else
         end
    end
end
```

...but that looks horrible.  Further, this is a notion that we'll be using around the app and I'd hate to pollute all the controllers like that.

What is the best practice for handling this situation?

Answer (score 0):

For a start `/issues/:id` should be handled by `IssuesController#show` not `#index`

You can choose to route `/:user_id/issues/:id` to any controller and action that you like.  There is not necessarily a best practice for this, so pick something you're happy with.  I'd route this to something like `IssuesController#show_for_user` so it was nice and clear.